# CSS :last-child and :not() used together to style an element

Tags: html, css

I have the following unordered list and CSS.

```css
.hideMe { display: none; }
li:last-child { background: blue}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>test 1</li>
  <li>test 2</li>
  <li>test 3</li>
  <li class="hideMe">test 5</li>
  <li>test 6</li>
  <li class="hideMe">test 7</li>
  <li class="hideMe">test 8</li>
</ul>
```

The last element that is visible needs to have special styling. In this case `<li>test 6</li>` should have a blue background.

I have tried a few different things.

```
li:last-child:not(.hideMe) { background: blue}
li:not(.hideMe):last-child { background: blue}
```

Neither work. I know this can be solved with JS, but I was hoping to solve it with CSS.

**Side Note:** This is not a case of previous/next siblings.

Any thoughts?

Comment: This wasn't about siblings. The answer is not in the related link.

Comment: About last visible child: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52968782/selecting-last-visible-child-using-css
I don't think it's possible using CSS only.